# I want to add overloaded operators to a derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, derived-class, base-class

## C++

I have been working hard on learning `Inheritance` and `Polymorphism` for weeks. I can have Mammals with Dogs and Cats, O can derive Puppy's from Dogs and what not. I have a *NaughtleNum `base class` with `a + operator`* And the `derived class` is Naughty1. (Sorry, but I hate Foo Bar)

**Here is the Code:**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char UCHAR;
typedef unsigned short int SHORT;

class NaughtleNum;
class Naughty1;

class NaughtleNum {
public:
    NaughtleNum() {
        cout << "Hello NaughtleNum 1\n";
    }; //constructors
    virtual~NaughtleNum() {
        cout << "Bye Bye NaughtleNum\n";
    }; //destructor
    virtual NaughtleNum * operator + (NaughtleNum * ) = 0;
};

class Naughty1: public NaughtleNum {
public: 
    Naughty1() {
        cout << "Hello Naughty1\n";
        value = 3;
    }; //constructors
    ~Naughty1() {
        cout << "Bye Bye Naughty1\n";
    }; //destructor
    Naughty1 * operator + (Naughty1 * ) {}
private: 
    UCHAR value;
};

int main() {

    cout << "I am Here\n";

    NaughtleNum * N1;
    N1 = new Naughty1;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to have `a + operator` for two Naughty Numbers!

**Messages are:**

```
daddio@LittleBeast:~/Programs/MyLib/Naughty> g++ -g -o NaughtleNum NaughtleNum.cpp
NaughtleNum.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
NaughtleNum.cpp:35:12: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Naughty1’
     N1=new Naughty1;
            ^
NaughtleNum.cpp:19:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Naughty1’:
 class Naughty1: public NaughtleNum
       ^
NaughtleNum.cpp:16:30: note:    virtual NaughtleNum* NaughtleNum::operator+(NaughtleNum*)
         virtual NaughtleNum* operator + (NaughtleNum*) =0;
                              ^
daddio@LittleBeast:~/Programs/MyLib/Naughty>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Mixing virtual functions and operator overloading is always painful and almost never necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error for an abstract class is because you haven't overridden the base class's binary addition operator! If you have a virtual operator in a base class, then the derived class *must* have the same signature for that operator.

```
Naughty1 * operator + (Naughty1 * ) {}
```

Is completely and 100% different from:

```
virtual NaughtleNum * operator + (NaughtleNum * ) = 0;
```

However, before you go out and change the signature so that they match, please consider if you *really* need operator polymorphism here. Each class is going to have its own unique binary addition operator, so there is no need for a virtual operator in the base class. It doesn't make sense for a `Naughty1` to have an addition operator that will return and accept a `Naughtlenum` but rather one that will accept and return a `Naughty1`.

On a side note, the addition operator should just return an object, not a pointer to it.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I had got somewhat frazzled when I posted the question Quite apart from not overloading assignment, it looks like I need to rethink the base class altogether.